# How to get the access key with iam_module of Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam

I am using Ansible to create AWS users. One of the features of Ansible is to create a user with access key. I am wondering how could I get the access key after the user was successfully created.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/iam_module.html

```
tasks:
- name: Create two new IAM users with API keys
  iam:
    iam_type: user
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    password: "{{ temp_pass }}"
    access_key_state: create
  with_items:
    - user
```

Comment: What is your ansible version?

Comment: 2.0.0.2 is the current version

Comment: It may work in 2,0,0,2. Register the results and try. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried in `2.0.1.0`. Should work in `2.0.0.2`.

```
  tasks:
  - iam:
      iam_type: user
      name: foo
      state: present
      access_key_state: create
    register: credentials
  - debug: var=credentials
```

**Output**

```
[debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "credentials": {
        "changed": false,
        "groups": null,
        "keys": {
            "AKIAXXXXXXXXXXTTGFXX": "Active"
        },
        "user_name": "foo"
    }
}
```

It is not possible to get the secret as of Ansible 2.0.1.0. It is a bug. See [iam module not very useful for managing access keys](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2821)

Comment: Do you think you can get the secret part of the key as well? It is only available at creation time.

Comment: It is not possible to get the secret now. See my update.

Comment: You are showing the access key but not the secret key. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/AWSCredentials.html

Answer (score 6):

In the meantime (I am using Ansible 2.3.2.0) that issue was successfully fixed:

```
- name: Create restricted bot user to access S3
  iam:
    iam_type: user
    name: blubaa  
    state: present
    access_key_state: create
  connection: local
  register: credentials

- debug: var=credentials
```

Output:

```
ok: [XXXXXXXXXX] => {
    "credentials": {
        "changed": true, 
        "groups": null, 
        "keys": [
            {
                "access_key_id": "AKIAJXXXXXXXXXXZX6GQ", 
                "create_date": "2017-08-26T01:04:05Z", 
                "status": "Active", 
                "user_name": "blubaa"
            }
        ], 
        "user_meta": {
            "access_keys": [
                {
                    "access_key_id": "AKIAJXXXXXXXXXXZX6GQ", 
                    "access_key_selector": "XXXX", 
                    "create_date": "2017-08-26T01:04:05.720Z", 
                    "secret_access_key": "wPwd2H0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXkHB08Elo", 
                    "status": "Active", 
                    "user_name": "blubaa"
                }
            ], 
            "created_user": {
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::30XXXXXXXXXX:user/blubaa", 
                "create_date": "2017-08-26T01:04:05.557Z", 
                "path": "/", 
                "user_id": "AIDAXXXXXXXXXXOYT7M", 
                "user_name": "blubaa"
            }, 
            "password": null
        }
    }
}
```